# Ionic/Angular $http.get returning Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an application in `IONIC`. I am making a `$http.get` request in Angular JS and its giving me `404` error when I successfully login and trying to load the user profile using the token sent in the authentication header.

It produces error in chrome, although I enabled `CORS`. Please check the [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lv4lshm4b835zuk/chrome0.png?dl=0):

[image: screenshot]

Now if I try the url in `POSTMAN`, everything is ok. See the [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zipu6lwr9xn57b9/postman.jpg?dl=0) below:

[image: screenshot 2]

I am stuck with this error, can someone help me?

Comment: you enabled CORS in php?

Comment: Please put all the relevant information in the question, not in links. And text is preferrable to images when it comes to errors and data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What Ionic says

> There are two ways to solve the issue: The first, and easier, solution is to just allow all origins from your API endpoint. However, we can’t always control the endpoint we are accessing. What we need, then, is a request that does not specify an origin.
>
> We can do this by using a proxy server. Let’s look how the Ionic CLI provides

[Reference](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/)

#### What works but isn't completely good to use

A simple solution is just add a CORS plugin into your browser and everything will work.

[Plugin Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

#### Proxy server

If you want a proxy server there is this tutorial:

[Link](http://ionicinaction.com/blog/how-to-fix-cors-problems-and-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-errors-with-ionic/)

Comment: Thanks Tiago Fabre. This worked for me: http://ionicinaction.com/blog/how-to-fix-cors-problems-and-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-errors-with-ionic/
But what happened why i will make the APP live and the server is on some domain. Should i need to install 'npm install -g corsproxy' there also? Looking for your reply.
Thanks again.

Comment: No, this problem is only happening because you are working with localhost. It only happens because the browser block every "complex" request (POST, PUT, DELETE...) from localhost by default. When you put your app in production that problem will not happen since the request is from a server. I am not an expert on that and but I already put ionic apps in production and I didn't have problems with CORS